# Google Sheets: Right vertical axis gridlines not working

Tags: google-sheets, charts

In Google Sheets, when creating a chart using both vertical axes, I can somehow turn on and off the gridlines for the (left) vertical axis but not for the right vertical axis.

In the first image, I'm showing the Major Gridlines option selected. If unselected, as expected, the gridlines turn off.

[image: Vertical Axis Gridlines]

The second image shows the same option selected for the right vertical axis, but no gridlines are shown.
[image: Right Vertical Axis Gridlines]

A curious fact I've been experiencing with Google Sheets (and maybe other Google's products), is that whenever I look up for "unusual customization" on Google's search engine, I only get the most basic results and, more often than not, they have nothing to do with what I was looking for. As an example, searching for *"sheets right vertical axis gridline not showing"* returns nothing relevant. Has anybody else noticed this?

Thanks

**What I've tried:** I've tried changing the color, with no effects.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I created a simple table with 6 rows, X from 1 to 6, and both Y1 and Y2 being random numbers from -5 to 5. The desired output are the Major Gridlines of the Right Vertical Axis (as it can be seen from the images).

Comment: I too have struggled with exactly this problem for quite some time. Googling for "right vertical axis gridlines not showing" brought me here. Unfortunately, I have not found a solution so far.

Comment: same for my chart. Exactly as it shown in the post, the "right vertical axis gridlines" is simply not working.

Comment: For clarification, are you trying to have both left and right vertical axes display gridlines at the same time? Whilst Excel does appear to allow this, it doesn't make for a very 'clean' chart, and I'm wondering if the bug here is that Google Sheets displays the option to add gridlines to the secondary axis at all (as opposed to it showing the option but it doesn't work)...

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a genuine bug. I have escalated the issue to Google.

To send a report of your own, and get notified of changes, open a spreadsheet and choose **Help > Report a Problem** or **Help > Help Sheets Improve**. If you are on a paid Google Workspace Domain, see [Contact Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).